# Clojure: Conversion from ArrayMap to HashMap

Tags: java, data-structures, clojure, hashmap

I'm looking into the clojure source code. The Implementation of `PersistentArrayMap` has this conditional in the `assoc` function:

```
    if(array.length >= HASHTABLE_THRESHOLD)
        return createHT(array).assoc(key, val);
```

Where `HASHTABLE_THRESHOLD` is 16. So assoc should return a `PersistentHashMap` if the arraymap already has 8 pairs. Now look at this clojure code:

```
(defn create [n, init] (if (= n 0) init (recur (dec n) (assoc init n n))))
(type (create 9 {}))
```

The output is `clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap`, shouldn't it be a `PersistentHashMap`? Which is what I get if I use 10 instead of 9.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug with `assoc` that's fixed in Clojure 1.10: https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1587 in [this commit](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/ce9fbf61f113fdef1cbf8c1c0b4ea1a48831beef) (never mind that the commit is 4 years old).

The bug only affected `assoc`, so some other ways of producing 9-key maps weren't affected:

```
Clojure 1.9.0
(type {9 9, 8 8, 7 7, 6 6, 5 5, 4 4, 3 3, 2 2, 1 1})
=> clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
(type (into {} (map vector (range 9) (range 9))))
=> clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
```

After the fix:

```
Clojure 1.10.0-beta4
(type (create 9 {}))
=> clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
```

Comment: It's weird to see a four year old commit to be included in a pretty recent clojure release. What might be the reason behind it?

Comment: Clojure's patch process is just not one you can reliably get contributions into in any predictable amount of time. As outsiders we can't make credible guesses as to why, just observe that indeed many patches linger for a long time before being either accepted or declined.